# Dask parsing Nested Json file to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I would really love some help with parsing nested JSON data using Dask.

This is an example of the JSON file (input), the result array in the json shown can have more than 3 elements, the shown json is just for illustrating the structure:

```
{"status":"success",

 "data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":

[{"metric":{"data0":"T" ,"data1":"O"},"values":[[90,"0"],[80, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data0":"K" ,"data1":"S"},"values":[[70,"0"],[60, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data2":"J" ,"data3":"O"},"values":[[50,"0"],[40, "0"]]}]}}
```

**My Goals** I would essentially want to get the data into the following data frames:

1-

```
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 |values
```

example output dataframe:

```
data0  | data1 | data2  | data3 | values
"T"    |   "O" |    nan |    nan|   [90,"0"],[80, "0"]
"K"    |   "S" |    nan |    nan|   [70,"0"],[60, "0"]
nan    |   nan |    "J" |    "O"|   [50,"0"],[40, "0"]
```

2-

```
time | value | data0 | data1 | data2 | data3
```

example output dataframe

```
time | value |data0 | data1 | data2  | data3 
90   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
80   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
70   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
60   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
50   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
40   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
```

Also , if there are any ways to speed up this process using dask's parallelism capabilities , that would be great because the parsed json files are in gigabytes.

Comment: Please see the guidelines on [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask). This is not a code-writing service. Post the code you've written and the specific place you're stuck. The way I'd approach this is to write a function that can do what you'd like on one file in memory using pandas, then parallelize this with dask using [`client.map`](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#map-and-submit-functions).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is I'm new to pandas and dask and I only know the basic, the is why I'm stuck on producing the dataframes listed on the question. So ,If you have any recommendation on how I would start forming the dataframes in panda , that would be great.

Comment: you can start here - https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html; see esp https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 1):

@AEAO, I have some answers to your question below, but also be sure to check out the [Dask discourse](https://dask.discourse.group/) page, which is more discussion-based and excellent for these types of usage questions!

I think something like this will work if you're not using Dask:

```py
import pandas as pd

# from your example
my_dict = {"status":"success",
 "data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":
[{"metric":{"data0":"T" ,"data1":"O"},"values":[[90,"0"],[80, "0"]]},
{"metric":{"data0":"K" ,"data1":"S"},"values":[[70,"0"],[60, "0"]]},
{"metric":{"data2":"J" ,"data3":"O"},"values":[[50,"0"],[40, "0"]]}]}}

# for your first goal
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_dict['data']['result'])
df1 = df1.join(
    pd.DataFrame(df1['metric'].to_list())
).drop('metric', axis=1)

# another way to achieve your first goal (and is faster here)
df1 = pd.json_normalize(my_dict['data']['result'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip('metric.')

# second goal
df2 = df1.explode('values')
df2[['time', 'value']] = df2['values'].to_list()
df2 = df2.drop('values', axis=1)
```

And then here's how you could use Dask:

```py
import json
import dask.bag as db
import dask.dataframe as dd

# setup, to show lazy reading next
with open('/tmp/data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f)

# create Dask bag
my_bag = db.read_text(
    '/tmp/data.json' # or can use data_*.json for multiple files
).map(
    json.loads # lazy loading
).pluck('data').pluck('result').flatten() # only take the ['data']['result'] values

# if you don't provide the meta argument, then not all columns will populate
metrics = my_bag.pluck('metric').to_dataframe(
    meta={'data0': str, 'data1': str, 'data2': str, 'data3': str})

# convert to a Dask dataframe and join columns together
lazy_df1 = my_bag.to_dataframe().join(metrics).drop('metric', axis=1)

# first goal, call .compute() to get your result
df1 = lazy_df1.compute()

# second goal
lazy_df2 = lazy_df1.explode('values')
values = lazy_df2.pop('values')
# Dask dataframe doesn't have the pd.Series.to_list() method
# so convert to Dask bag first
df2 = lazy_df2.join(
    values.to_bag().to_dataframe(meta={'time': int, 'value':str})
).compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. There is a problem in the first solution in this part ``` pd.DataFrame(df['metric'].to_list()) ``` . The IDE shows an error that df is not identified. The second solution shows an error too. Have you tried to run the code on an IDE?

Comment: thanks, just edited